# matplotlib plot line with color controlled by a third variable, ask for better solution

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I know there are several questions about this in stackoverflow, but the current solution still has some problems.

I am following the solution provided by http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/dpsanders/matplotlib-examples/blob/master/colorline.ipynb using `LineCollection`.

Actually it works. But when I save the figure into PDF file. After zooming in, it looks not very good. The size of PDF file is hundreds of times of simply plot without changing color. I understand why it looks like this. Is there any idea to plot the color-line smoother?
[image]

Comment: Why are you saving to PDF rather than an image file?

Comment: Because I want to insert the figure into `latex`. Usually I save the figure in `PDF` format.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183462/saving-images-in-python-at-a-very-high-quality

Comment: Since this problem probably requires to do some testing, you should provide a [mcve] of the issue, including the code to draw one such linecollection and a clear statement at which zoom level tzhis occurs