# Saving Python (matplotlib) figures as eps with text as tex files

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, tikz

I have been a regular user of Matlab for plotting. I use [`matlabfrag`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21286-matlabfrag) to save figures as `eps` for the plot along with a `tex` file containing labels. The complete plot can be rendered in Latex upon calling the eps and tex files together.

Now that I switched to Python, I am wondering if there is any equivalent of `matlabfrag` for Python? I am aware of `matplotlib2tikz` but would like to avoid compute overload for generating plots each time on compiling Latex, as there are way too many plots sometimes.

PS: In the end, I am looking for plots with Latex-like fonts with a controllable font size. Reduced compute load is another requirement.

Comment: I think that link can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183462/saving-images-in-python-at-a-very-high-quality

Comment: Is including an eps really faster than including a tikz/pgf?  Matplotlib has a pgf backend, though I think it might have a few foibles. However, I will also suggest you buck the conventions of your field and not insist that your plots have the same fonts as your text.  That made sense 20 years ago when LaTeX was the only way to get equations in figures at all.  That is not at all the case anymore.  Or, if you insist on LaTeX, Matplotlib can render it directly in most backends: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html